# Display all records that are stored in SQlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to display all my records that are stored in the database

```
c = db.DBhelper.getChamp1(c.getCount);
//startManagingCursor(c);
int j = 0;
stateNameArray = new String[c.getCount()];
c.moveToFirst();
while(!c.isAfterLast()) {
  stateNameArray[j] = c.getString(0);
  j++;
  Log.i("DEBUG_SQL","" + c.getString(0)+ " "+c.getString(j));
   c.moveToNext();
}
//String resultat = ;
Log.i("DEBUG_SQL","" + c.getColumnIndex("article"));
```

I get an error when I write `c.getCount` – why?  When I write a number like 1 or 2 or 3... that works.

And if I write

```
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM loan", null);
```

I get an error, but if I write

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM loan WHERE _id=1", null);
```

That works. Why?

Comment: Now it'd really help in the future to check how your post looks. Indent code by using the `{}` button or `Ctrl-K`, and don't put your actual question *inside* the code.

Comment: `c = db.DBhelper.getChamp1(c.getCount);`  What he heck is this supposed to do? It looks like a circular reference to me.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, I see a problem with this log statement, where c.getString(j) doesn't make sense.  And it may trigger an error as j gets larger.

```
 Log.i("DEBUG_SQL","" + c.getString(0)+ " "+c.getString(j));
```

What data did you intend to access with the statement c.getString(j)?

On the getCount error.  I assumed the error in the following was a typo.  But is this where the error associated with getCount was located?

```
c = db.DBhelper.getChamp1(c.getCount);
```

But I shouldn't assume - you never know.  It should read (add brackets to the method call).

```
c = db.DBhelper.getChamp1(c.getCount());
```

And as @Barak mentioned, what is going on with this statement?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question about your getCount isuue, you get the error because of this:

```
c = db.DBhelper.getChamp1(c.getCount);
```

You're trying to get the count of the cursor before you have it (and you're missing `()`).

This would work since you have a cursor to count before you pull the next one:

```
c = db.getSomeCursor;
c1 = db.DBhelper.getChamp1(c.getCount());
```

Let us know what you're trying to achieve (I can't figure it out from the code you posted) and maybe we can be more helpful.